# Getting the updated state after an action is dispatched in redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am using react and redux.

I have a Container component defined as so:

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import {addTag} from 'actions';
import ExpenseTagsControl from './expense_tags_control'

const mapStateToProps = (state, own_props={selected_tags:[]}) => {
    return {
        tags_list: state.tags.tags_list
    };
};


const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        addTag: (tag_name) => {
            dispatch(addTag(tag_name))
        }
    };
};

const AddExpenseTagsContainer = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(ExpenseTagsControl);


export default AddExpenseTagsContainer;
```

The container wraps a presentational component which is defined as so:

```
// expense_tags_control.js
import React, {Component, PropTypes} from 'react';
import ChipInput from 'material-ui-chip-input';
import Chip from 'material-ui/Chip';
import Avatar from 'material-ui/Avatar';
import Tag from 'common/svg_icons/tag';
import AutoComplete from 'material-ui/AutoComplete'

import _ from 'underscore';



class ExpenseTagsControl extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            chips: []
        };
    };

    handleAdd(chip) {

          // If the chip does not already exist, add it. the id here will be a dummy value that is not there in the tags_list
        if (!(_.contains( _.map(this.props.tags_list, (tag) => tag.id), chip.id))) {
            this.props.addTag(chip.name);
        }

          // This is wrong.     
        this.setState({
            chips: [...this.state.chips, chip]
        });
    };

    handleDelete(chip) {
        this.setState({
            chips: this.state.chips.filter((c) => c !== deletedChip)
        });
    };


    chipRenderer({ text, value, isFocused, isDisabled, handleClick, handleRequestDelete }, key) {
        const style = {
            margin: '8px 8px 0 0',
            float: 'left',
            pointerEvents: isDisabled ? 'none' : undefined
        };

        return (
            <Chip key={key} style={style} onTouchTap={handleClick} onRequestDelete={handleRequestDelete}>
                <Avatar size={24} icon={<Tag />} />
                {text}
            </Chip>
        );
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <ChipInput
                hintText="Tags"
                value={this.state.chips}
                onRequestAdd={(chip) => this.handleAdd(chip)}
                onRequestDelete={(deletedChip) => this.handleDelete(deletedChip)}
                fullWidth={true}
                dataSourceConfig={{ text: 'name', value: 'id' }}
                dataSource={this.props.tags_list}
                chipRenderer={this.chipRenderer}
                openOnFocus={false}
                filter={AutoComplete.fuzzyFilter}
                onRequestDelete={console.log("Deleted")}
            />);
    };
};

ExpenseTagsControl.PropTypes = {
    tags_list: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
    addTag: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    value: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
    onChange: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

export default ExpenseTagsControl;
```

The presentational component above, maintains a state, which indicates the chips that have been selected.

The [ChipInput](https://github.com/TeamWertarbyte/material-ui-chip-input) component allows you to select chips which are objects with an id, and a name,  defined from a pre-existing data source. The component also allows you to add a new chip by typing in the name. If the typed in name does not exist in the data source, it is added to the data source.

**My Problem**

The id of the newly added chip is assigned once the `addTag()` action is dispatched. How do I get the value of the result of the action that was just dispatched?

I thought about working around this by maintaining the state of the ChipInput in the global state, and manipulate the global state upon dispatching the addTag() action. But that feels like too much overhead.

Comment: You can just remove the state from ExpenseTagsControl and put it in Redux. Then pass it back using your AddExpenseTagsContainer map.

Answer (score 1):

If what I understand is correct, you might want something like this:

```
class ExpenseTagsControl extends React.Component {

    // ...


    /*
     * assuming your reducers are working fine and 'addTag'
     * has updated global 'state.tags.tags_list'
     */
    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        this.setState({ chips: this.nextProps.tags_list });
    }

    // ...
}
```

**NB:** You might need to optimize calling `setState` inside `componentWillReceiveProps` based on some conditions to avoid unnecessary re-render.

Comment: tags_list is a list of tags that are available. I am passing them to this component so that it can render the autocomplete. They are not the actual selected values. Sorry I was not more clear.

Comment: As I said, I assumed `dispatch(addTag(tag_name))` is updating `state.tags.tags_list` in some reducer. Could you post the reducer code?

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, the OP's problem is how to dispatch an action to modify the redux store and at the same time update the component's local state.

*Edit: added a working example*

```js
const initialState = {
  tags: ['hello', 'hi', 'howdy']
}

function reducer(state = {}, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'ADD_TAG':
      return {
        ...state,
        tags: [
          ...state.tags,
          action.payload.tag
        ]
      }
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

const store = Redux.createStore(reducer, initialState);

const addTag = (tag) => ({
  type: 'ADD_TAG',
  payload: {
    tag
  }
})

class Chips extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.chipToAdd = false;
      this.state = {
        chips: []
      }
      this.handleAdd = this.handleAdd.bind(this);
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
      console.log(this.chipToAdd);
      if (this.chipToAdd) {
        this.setState({
          chips: [...this.state.chips, this.chipToAdd]
        }, (this.chipToAdd = false));
      }
    }

    handleAdd(chip) {
      if (this.props.tags.filter(tag => tag === chip).length === 0) {
        this.chipToAdd = chip;
        this.props.addTag(chip);
      } else {
        if (this.state.chips.filter(existingChip => existingChip === chip).length === 0) {
          this.setState({
            chips: [...this.state.chips, chip]
          });
        }
      }
    }

    render() {
        return <div >
          < h3 > Tags added in component 's chip state</h3>
   <ul>
    {this.state.chips.map((chip, index) => <li key={index}>{chip}</li>)}
   </ul>
   <hr />
   <h3>Tags in Redux Store</h3>
   {this.props.tags.map(
    (tag, index) => <li key={index}>
     {tag} <button onClick={() => this.handleAdd(tag)}>Add</button>
    </li>
   )}
   <button onClick={() => this.handleAdd('
        new tag - ' + Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1))}>Add a chip with new tag</button>
  </div>
 }
}

const mapStateToProps = ({ tags = [] }) => ({ tags });
const ConnectedChips = ReactRedux.connect(mapStateToProps, { addTag })(Chips);

class App extends React.Component {
 render() {
  return <div>
   <h1>React/Redux Demo</h1>
   <ConnectedChips />
  </div>
 }
}

const Provider = ReactRedux.Provider;

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}><App /></Provider>,
    document.getElementById('
        root ')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/redux@3.6.0/dist/redux.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-redux@4.4.6/dist/react-redux.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Care to elaborate why it's not recommended? It worked when I tested it.

Comment: You edited it so now it works.But it's surely a kludgy way to pass state around. If you click fast enough you might overwrite the chipToAdd property before it's used (this is entirely legal since React doesn't guarantee it'll call your methods at any particular time). Also, the reason React calls your componentWillReceiveProps to even do anything is not simple or straightforward. It is related to React-Redux and your mapStateToProps and when this changes for any reason, the connection from calling addTag to componentWillReceiveProps may be lost, meaning the code won't run and this will break.

Comment: Working is better than nothing. It would definitely makes it easier to implement if it's all in Redux store. On the other hand, I also see the point of not putting this to the global state. It makes sense to use local state if it's only needed in that component.